# Iterate over dataframe columns to calculate velocity using np.gradient()

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have two dataframes, `LP_pos` and `vel`, where `LP_pos` contains position data to be used to calculate velocity, which will go into the second dataframe.

I want to calculate velocity of each row of the df using `np.gradient()`, by iterating over the columns of df1 and creating a new column in df2 with the info calculated with gradient. Here's what I have so far

```
# create a new column for velocity
def vel(df1, df2):
    for col in df1:
        df2[col + '_vel'] = np.gradient(df1[col], df1['Time'])
    return df2

vel(LP_pos, vel)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c69328603d12> in <module>
      5     return df2
      6 
----> 7 vel(LP_pos, vel)

<ipython-input-14-c69328603d12> in vel(df1, df2)
      2 def vel(df1, df2):
      3     for col in df1:
----> 4         df2[col + '_vel'] = np.gradient(df1[col], df1['Time'])
      5     return df2
      6 

TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**Sample Data:**

```
    Time    X           Y           Z
0   0.00    0.245740    0.204112    0.168514    
1   0.01    0.245737    0.204115    0.168523    
2   0.02    0.245732    0.204117    0.168532    
3   0.03    0.245723    0.204118    0.168541
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    Time    X_vel       Y_vel       Z_vel
0   0.00    grad(X1)    grad(Y1)    grad(Z1)    
1   0.01    grad(X2)    grad(Y2)    ... 
2   0.02    grad(X3)    ...         ...
3   0.03    grad(X4)    ...         ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second dataframe has the same name as your function (`vel`) and thus shadows this dataframe.  Just use another name for either the second dataframe or your function, e.g.

```
def calculate_vel(df1, df2):
    for col in df1:
        df2[col + '_vel'] = np.gradient(df1[col], df1['Time'])
    return df2

calculate_vel(LP_pos, vel)
```

Comment: No problem, btw you can do the same in just one line `vel = pd.DataFrame(np.gradient(df, df.Time, axis=0), columns=[f'{c}_vel' for c in df.columns])`